# Показ времени работы процесса из БД php в реальном времени

Tags: php, mysql, daemon

Не могу никак сообразить.

В общем есть таблица в бд вида:

Таблица в БД

[image: 123]

В ней логируется запуск, пауза и остановка процесса.

Хотелось бы узнать: как мне посчитать время работы процесса, т.е. работа процесса это состояние 1, стоп это 2 и пауза это 0

Как узнать общее время работы процесса в виде 0:00:00:00 (дни:часы:минуты:секунды) в реальном времени

Сделал так

```
    public function _activityTimer($queues)
{

    $worked = 0;

    if (is_array($queues) and count($queues)) {

        foreach ($queues as $queue) {

            switch ($queue['event']) {

                case 1:

                    $start = $queue['timestamp'];

                    break;

                default:

                    $worked += $queue['timestamp'] - $start;

            }

        }

    }

    return $this->tpu->secondsToTime($worked);

}

public function secondsToTime($inputSeconds)
{

    $secondsInAMinute = 60;
    $secondsInAnHour = 60 * $secondsInAMinute;
    $secondsInADay = 24 * $secondsInAnHour;

    // extract days
    $days = floor($inputSeconds / $secondsInADay);

    // extract hours
    $hourSeconds = $inputSeconds % $secondsInADay;
    $hours = floor($hourSeconds / $secondsInAnHour);

    // extract minutes
    $minuteSeconds = $hourSeconds % $secondsInAnHour;
    $minutes = floor($minuteSeconds / $secondsInAMinute);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $remainingSeconds = $minuteSeconds % $secondsInAMinute;
    $seconds = ceil($remainingSeconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        'days' => (int) $days,
        'hours' => (int) $hours,
        'minutes' => (int) $minutes,
        'seconds' => (int) $seconds,
    );

    return $obj;

}
```

Но он к сожалению показывает все сначала т.е. 0:00:00:00
В теле страницы есть js скрипт который получает от php начальное время и начинает отсчет как бы в реальном времени. Так по этому скрипту начинается отсчет от нуля так как php выдает 0.

Подскажите как сделать отсчет время работы скрипта?

Comment: в php есть функция (-ции) который таймштамп в дату переводят. Зачем вы свой велосипед городите?

Comment: Ну мне надо не дату переводить а именно считать из бд сколько скрипт работает исключая время пауз, чисто когда скрипт в статусе "1"

Answer (score 0):

Вашим кодом вы обязываете, что должно быть четное число записей и на каждой нечетной позиции (и только там), должен быть запуск. Наверное это не совсем верно.

- Будем исходить из того, что массив `$queues` у вас отсортирован по времени. Это **необходимое** условие
- Далее, т.к. у вас напутано, что такое старт и стоп (в вопросе одно, а в комментарии к таблице - другое), я определю константы  явно
- Ну и я буду исходить из того, что время в таблице, это время **включения** статуса, а не завершение

```php
define('STOP', 0);
define('START', 1);
define('PAUSE', 2);

public function _activityTimer($queues) {
  $worked = 0;
  $start = 0;  // Изначально процесс остановлен
  if (is_array($queues)) {
    foreach($queues as $queue) {
      if ($queue['event'] == START) {
        if ($start == 0)  // Если ранее процесс был не запущен, то фиксируем время запуска
          $start = $queue['timestamp'];
      } else {
        if ($start != 0) {  // Если ранее процесс был запущен, то суммируем время работы
          $worked += $queue['timestamp'] - $start;
          $start = 0;  // процесс остановлен
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if ($start != 0) // процесс еще не остановлен
    $worked += time() - $start;  // Добавляем время работы до текущего времени
  return $this->tpu->secondsToTime($worked);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую отпишусь!